# Fundamental Theorem of Algebra - an elementary complex analysis proof?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, alternative-proof, complex-integration

We begin by assuming that a non-constant complex polynomial $$p(z)=a_n z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1 z+a_0,$$ where $a_0 \neq 0$, doesn't vanish in $\mathbb{C}$. Therefore $1/p$ is also an analytical function everywhere. Note that $(p(z)-a_0)/z$ is a polynomial and therefore, due to Cauchy's theorem, the following integral must be zero.

$$\int_{S_r^1}\frac{(p(z)-a_0)/z}{p(z)}dz=\int_{S_r^1}\frac{a_nz^{n-1}+a_{n-1}z^{n-2}+...+a_1}{a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1 z+a_0}dz=0.$$

On the other hand

$$\int_{S_r^1}\frac{a_nz^{n-1}+a_{n-1}z^{n-2}+...+a_1}{a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1 z+a_0}dz$$

$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{a_n(re^{i\theta})^{n-1}+a_{n-1}(re^{i\theta})^{n-2}+...+a_1}{a_n(re^{\theta})^n+a_{n-1}(re^{i\theta})^{n-1}+...+a_1 (re^{i\theta})+a_0}(ire^{i\theta})d\theta$$

$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}i d\theta - \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{a_0 i}{a_n(re^{i\theta})^n+a_{n-1}(re^{i\theta})^{n-1}+...+a_1 (re^{i\theta})+a_0}d\theta$$ $$=2\pi i -\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{a_0i}{p(re^{i\theta})}d\theta.$$

Let $r \rightarrow \infty$ and the integral approaches value $2\pi i$ - a contradiction. Therefore $1/p$ can't be entire and $p$ must vanish somewhere in the complex plane.

**EDIT:** *I have changed this post and deleted the idea that the integral $\int_{\partial D_r}\frac{(p(z)-a_0)/z}{p(z)}dz=0$ could be evaluated with the fundamental theorem of calculus. Now, as it stands, this proof is essentially the same as the one that Mr. José Carlos Santos points out in his comment.*

Comment: Your $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $D_r$, hence your equalities hold. But I don't see the relation with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @Aretino Indeed. But I want to avoid Cauchy's theorem or formula. If we can find that primitive then, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, that integral vanishes.

Comment: @Hulkster My article *The fundamental theorem of Algebra deduced from elementary Calculus* (The Mathematical Gazette **91**, issue 521, 2007, pp. 302–303) contains a proof of the Fundamental theorem of Algebra which uses only the Fundamental theorem of Calculus and the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, I know your article. But I'm wondering if we can find a primitive for that $f(z)$.

Comment: @Hulkster Avoiding Cauchy's theorem or formula? I doubt that.

Comment: More ways to prove the FTA than you can shake a stick at, at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra – maybe one of them will make you happy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! My proof same as the second one in https://mathoverflow.net/q/10608

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes. One must use Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at pages 120-125 of [my course notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).
If by *the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus* you mean *the residue Theorem* / *Cauchy's integral formula* (which can be seen as consequences of Stokes' Theorem, i.e. a generalized version of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) the answer is *yes*.

Assume that $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ fulfills $n\geq 1$, $a_0\neq 0$ and has no complex roots. In such a case $f(z)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\frac{1}{z\cdot p(z)}$ is a meromorphic function with a unique singularity, which is the simple pole at the origin. By the residue Theorem, for any $R>0$ we have

$$ \oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{z\cdot p(z)} = \frac{2\pi i}{p(0)} \neq 0 \tag{1}$$
but since $|p(z)|\to +\infty$ as $|z|\to +\infty$, the LHS of $(1)$ is arbitrarily close to zero by the triangle inequality. This contradiction proves that any non-constant polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[z]$ has at least a complex zero.

Gauss' original proof went close to proving the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra by using real instruments only, but at some point one has to invoke something more-or-less equivalent to [$\pi^1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) or to the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem), since real results only are not powerful enough to prove something about $\mathbb{C}\simeq \mathbb{R}^2$. Have a look at [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10535/ways-to-prove-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra), too.

It is worth mentioning an equivalent version of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra: by associating a polynomial with its companion matrix, we get that in order to prove the FTA it is enough to show that

> Any (WLOG, non-singular) $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries has an eigenvector.

For such a purpose, one may invoke the [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

Comment: Thanks for answering! What I want to do is to find a proof with very elementary complex integral methods, i.e. not concerning whether a function is holomorphic.

Comment: @Hulkster: how do you plane to prove that a non-constant polynomial with complex coefficients always has a complex root by using only real instruments? Gauss' original proof went close to achieving that, but at some point you have to use something more-or-less equivalent to $\pi^1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$ or to Jordan curve theorem, since real results only are not powerful enough to prove something about $\mathbb{C}\simeq\mathbb{R}^{\color{red}{2}}$ alone.

Comment: You can see that I'm using complex theory. If there is a way to find primitive for $f(z)$ the proof is simple. Surely $f(z)$ is holomorphic but I don't want to use Cauchy's theorem. Maybe that integral is impossible (without FTA that we are proving here).

Comment: It's clear that there can't be primitive since due to assumption and Cauchy's theorem that integral must be zero! Anyway, now I know what is the most direct proof of FTA in complex analysis :)